# Has the 400 bug in the twitter api been fixed yet?

Tags: php, twitter

[Bulletproof Twitter followers count with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159191/bulletproof-twitter-followers-count-with-php)

I am reviving this question because it is happening to me that, without any change in code, sometimes my program works, sometimes it doesn't.

> failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

This error message comes from the line

```
$user = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/'.$twitter.'.xml'));
```

AND

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/'.$twitter.'.json'));
```

Why does this sometimes work and sometimes not? I know it's not the maximum requests per hour because I come into work and see it right away when no one else uses my API key. Please can someone tell me what keeps going wrong or if it's all Twitter's fault?

Comment: Twitter's fail whale is known for a reason, their services are unreachable an almost insane amount of time / intervals. If the exact same request succeeds with a non-400 error, you can bet ya Twitter is the cause. Make very sure however that the requests are exactly identical.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP 400 responses](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/responses_errors) are returned during [rate limiting](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). Since you are not authenticating it is plausible that you are using your 150 request/hour per IP.

You can make authenticated requests to increase your limit to 350 requests/hour using [TwitterOAuth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) or a number of other [PHP libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#php).